# How to configure i18n with withFonts()

Tags: internationalization, next.js, tailwind-css, i18next

I am working on a Next.js project using Tailwind CSS for styling. I am stuck at the `next.config` file.

I've almost tried everything to make this code work but cannot.

```js
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const withImages = require("next-images");
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withFonts = require("next-fonts");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = withFonts(
  withCSS(
    withImages(
      withSass({
        webpack(config, options) {
          config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
            use: {
              loader: "url-loader",
            },
          });
          config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve("./"));
          return config;
        },
      })
    )
  )
);

module.exports = {
  i18n: {
    locales: ['en', 'fr'],
    defaultLocale: 'en',
  },
}
```

I'd like to know how to combine these two things.

Here is the code of the `index.js` i'm using.

```js
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import fr from '../locales/fr';
import en from '../locales/en';

function sth () {
  const router = useRouter();
  const { locale } = router;
  const t = locale === 'en' || 'undefined' ? en : fr;
  console.log(locale);

  return t;
}
export default function Index() {
  const t  = sth();
  return (
    <>
      <IndexNavbar fixed />
      <section className="header relative pt-16 items-center flex h-screen max-h-860-px">
        <div className="container mx-auto items-center flex flex-wrap">
          <div className="w-full md:w-8/12 lg:w-6/12 xl:w-6/12 px-4">
            <div className="pt-32 sm:pt-0">
              <h2 className="font-semibold text-4xl text-gray-700">
                {t.homeMainTitle}
              </h2>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </section>
    </>
);}
```

The content of `sth()` function was inside the `Index()` and it doesn't work either way.

Answer (score 2):

You can only have one `module.exports` per file/module. Your `next.config.js` should look like the following:

```js
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const withImages = require("next-images");
const withSass = require("@zeit/next-sass");
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
const withFonts = require("next-fonts");
const webpack = require("webpack");
const path = require("path");

module.exports = withFonts(
  withCSS(
    withImages(
      withSass({
        i18n: {
          locales: ['en', 'fr'],
          defaultLocale: 'en',
        },
        webpack(config, options) {
          config.module.rules.push({
            test: /\.(eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
            use: {
              loader: "url-loader",
            },
          });
          config.resolve.modules.push(path.resolve("./"));
          return config;
        },
      })
    )
  )
);
```

The object that you pass to the inner-most plugin (`withSass()` in this case) is your [Next config](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/next.config.js/introduction) object.

**Edit:** As for your component's code, you can't call a hook - in this case `useRouter` - from within a function like that. You'll need to move it to the component.

```js
export default function Index() {
    const router = useRouter();
    const { locale } = router;
    const t = locale === 'en' ? en : fr;
    
    return (
        // Your render code
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your respond, I've tried this before, the application is starting fine and everything. but still can't detect the language. I use `useRouter()` to get the user`s language. The value is undefined.

Comment: Could you add your component's code where you're trying to detect the language to your original question please?

Comment: @azzmi You'll need to move the code in `sth()` to the component itself. Check my updated answer.

Comment: I did what you said. But. Nothing changes. I still get the French version, The problem isn't in the `useRouter()` part. Because even the route `/fr` isn't there. I get the French version in the main route which supposed to be in English in a normal world, that is so weird.

Comment: One more thing, my app works fine when i delete the `withFonts()` part and all the components that depends on it. It works fine for English as Default and frensh with `/fr`

Comment: Do you absolutely need to use `next-fonts`? Fonts have had built-in support by Next.js for a while https://github.com/rohanray/next-fonts/issues/34.

Comment: Are you saying that It's impossible to use both `withFonts()` and `i18n`

Comment: Not saying it's impossible (I'm not entirely sure what is causing the issue). I'm just asking if you actually need to use `next-fonts` since Next.js already has fonts support built-in.